# App privado Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

Existe a possibilidade de fazer o *upload* de um aplicativo para o Google Play e o mesmo só está disponível para uma lista de usuários de meu interesse?

Como acontece no youtube que só pode ver aquele vídeo quem tem permissão de visualização aquele link. Tenho a seguinte situação, preciso que meu *app* esteja disponível para *download* para apenas alguns usuários que eu liberei.

Mas não gostaria de colocar esse *APK* em um servidor fora do Google Play. Existe algum modo de fazer isso?

Comment: Quando você está adicionando um app, você pode especificar ele como Alfa ou Beta. Mas não sei como fica visibilidade dele nessas condições.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sim, como o Lucas disse, se você configurar sua aplicação em fase alpha ou beta, o aplicativo não ficará visível ao público no google play.

Para dar acesso a um grupo limitado de pessoas, você poderá configurar comunidades do google+ ou do google groups, é claro que as pessoas precisam participar para poder ter acesso ao app. Todas as pessoas são consideradas testadoras e poderão mediante a aceitação, baixar e atualizar o aplicativo a partir do google play, assim como um usuário de um app qualquer.

As imagens abaixo mostram como configurar isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado @Wakim.

Answer (score 7):

Se você tem uma empresa ou trabalha para uma e ela é cadastrada no Google Apps for Business isto também é possível e da maneira criada para isso. O nome se chama Canal Privado da Google Play.

1. A empresa precisa ter um cadastro no Google Apps for Business
2. O Administrador do Google Apps precisa ativar o Google Wallet e Google Play Developer Console.
3. O Administrador do Google Apps precisa ativar o serviço do Google Play Developer Console para dispositivos mobile.
4. Algum funcionário deve se registrar no Google Play Developer Console (Lembrando que são $25, de preferência um email que não fique vinculado a um funcionário)
5. O email cadastrado no Google Play Developer Console deve fazer upload do apk e restringir a exibição somente para pessoas com email de seu mesmo domínio.

Referência: [Canal Privado da Google Play](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2623322?hl=pt-BR)