# O que eu preciso fazer para que meu app não seja reconhecido como "Fonte Desconhecida"?

Tags: android, download, instalador

Eu gostaria de saber qual é o procedimento que devo seguir para poder postar meu App no meu site e os usuários possam instalar sem que precisem ativar a opção de "Fontes Desconhecidas" dentro do menu Segurança do Android.

Se alguém pudesse me ajudar eu seria muito grato.

Comment: Publicar na Google Play. \o/. Pois essa opção é para instalar Apps por fora da Store da Google

Comment: Diogo, se a aplicação é específica, ainda assim você pode publicar na Google Play e esse app ser restrito a pessoas que você queira, dá uma olhada nessa pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16305/app-privado-google-play/16321#16321

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada sim, obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Diogo, por recomendação do Google e convenção, não é possível liberar um APK fora do Google Play e mesmo assim ser considerado "seguro". Você pode enviar sem problemas o APK par seus amigos, mas esta mensagem vai continuar aparecendo.

Você pode cadastrar o aplicativo no Google Play em versão beta ou alpha e liberar para apenas um grupo de usuários, [veja nesse link oficial](https://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/developer-console.html#alpha-beta).

Abraços!

Answer (score 1):

Caso seja um app público a melhor maneira é publicar na própria playstore.

Link para publicação:
https://play.google.com/apps/publish/signup/

Comment: Mas é uma aplicação específica para os meus clientes e eu gostaria que apenas eles pudessem baixar.